# How do I make a pong response from golang.org/x/websocket?

Tags: go, websocket

I would like to be able to respond "pong" when I get "ping" for the keep alive connection on `golang.org/x/websocket` impl.

It seems that it's not supported natively.
Is it possible to implement it? How to proceed?

```
srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:              ":3000",
        ReadTimeout:       12 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:       12 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:      12 * time.Second,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 12 * time.Second,
    }

    http.Handle("/websocket", websocket.Handler(handler))
```